# What is the use of single and double quotes in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, quotes

I'm passing a string or number to a SQL query.

What is the meaning of single quotes and a single within double quotes?

```
select * from college where class = '"+txtclass.Text+"'
```

or

```
select * from college where class = '+txtclass.Text+'
```

Comment: @SudiptaMondalm that link raises more questions than answers...

Comment: The first example appears to have been presented out of context: it looks like the code is concatenating strings to make a query. (That is the wrong way to do it: SQL parameters should be used to pass parameters to the query.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL server

Comment: Also: you should ***NOT*** concatenate your SQL with user-provided values like this - this is **WIDE OPEN** to SQL injections. Whatever database system you're using *most likely* will support something like **parametrized queries** - using those avoids SQL injections - and makes many of those quote-related problems go away, too

Comment: @marc_s It looks like that is a snippet taken from, say, a line of C#. Your edit may be obfuscating that.

Comment: @YabazThampi Is there more code around that snippet? It would probably help to see it. And also let us know which programming language you're using.

Comment: Single quotes are T-SQL's string delimiters. The double quote has no special meaning *within a string*. It's the difference between the strings `"+txtclass.Text+"` and `+txtclass.Text+`, where the difference likely matters to whoever is consuming that string. (Double quotes can also be used in T-SQL, not for strings but to escape identifiers, and that purpose is not relevant here.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm using c# programming language I need to know the meaning single Quotes or single quotes within double quotes  Example :insert into emi_details(ic_no,loan_id) values('" + this.ddl_icno.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + this.ddl_loanid.SelectedValue + "',)"

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thankuu man

Comment: @YabazThampi, please heed the comment about using parameters instead of string concatenation in the app code. This has many benefits including cleaner code, better security, performance, etc.

Comment: @YabazThampi The double quotes are not in the SQL. They are in the C# code.

Answer (score -1):

You should use parameters for the SqlCommand.

Here a small example on how to do it:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("conection string"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Here is where we add the parameters into the Sql Query, this way it will prevent SQL Injection
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from college where class = @class";
        // Now we add the value to the parameter @class, I'm assuming here that the column class is a NVarchar
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtclass.Text;
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // Do some code
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

this example is for Sql, but the same can be done to MySql, we just need to use the MySql  classes, the rest is the same

Note: I know this doesn't answer the question that as been made, but since there is a security risk the way he is doing, I decided to give an simple example how to make it more secure, since the answer as been given on the comments on the question

Comment: Do NOT use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Humm thanks for the warning, I did use AddWithValue because it would require less code. Need to research a little more so I can change the solutions that I have to remove the AddWithValue

Comment: @Camadas You should specify the size of string parameters otherwise it might default to 1 and silently truncate the data.